# Passing an object through a method via it's constructor in Java?

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I'm trying to pass the String `label` into my method `toString()` from the constructors String of the same name. However, I keep getting an error telling me that `label` cannot be resolved to a variable. Here's my code:

```
public class LabeledPoint extends java.awt.Point {

    LabeledPoint(int x, int y, String label){
        setLocation(x, y);

    }

    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "[x=" + x + ",y=" + y + ",label=" + label + "]";
    }


}
```

I've been able to infer that it has something to do with the body of the constructor, but I can't figure out what. Thank you.

Comment: Your class doesn't have a member named `label`. And your constructor doesn't do anything with the string either

Comment: Your `toString()` method cannot possibly understand what variable `label` is referring to.

Comment: How do I pass `label` into the method from the constructor?

Comment: You don't. You need to store the value being passed into the constructor somewhere, and then use it in `toString()`.  You can't pass the value directly from the constructor to `toString()`, because you aren't calling `toString()` from the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the **label** variable within your LabeledPoint class:

```
public class LabeledPoint extends java.awt.Point {
    private String label;
    LabeledPoint(int x, int y, String label){
        setLocation(x, y);
        this.label = label;
    }

    public LabeledPoint setLabel (String final label){
        this.label = label;
        return this;
    }

    public String getLabel (){
        return label;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "[x=" + x + ",y=" + y + ",label=" + this.getLabel() + "]";
    }
}
```

Edit: applied suggestions from @Stephen P

Comment: a couple of things … I would make it `private final String label` unless you want it changeable; in that case it would be `private String label` (you should _nearly_ always use `private`) and you would need `public LabeledPoint setLabel(final String newLabel) { this.label = newLabel; return this; }` (I return `this` in setters so they can be chained)